# Is there any way to compress a huge database table oon PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, compression

I have a PostgreSQL database with a huge table (**2 Billion records**) and I'm looking for any solution to **compress the table content**.

Here is the description of my table:

[image: Table description]

My question: is there any way to compress the table?

Comment: There is no such option in PostgreSQL. Do you want to save disk space, or do you have another reason?

Comment: I want to save disk space

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to compress a table like this in PostgreSQL, sorry.

You can save a couple of bytes (padding) by arranging the columns carefully: start with the `timestamp`, `bigint` and `double precision` columns (8 bytes), then the `integer` and `boolean` columns (4 bytes), then the columns with variable length.

But that would only buy you a few bytes per row, and it cannot be done without rewriting the table, which is probably not an option.
All the space you could gain is probably dwarfed by the overhead, fragmentation and bloat in the table, which is (to some extent) unavoidable.

I would invest into getting more storage space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! what do you think about using varchar or text columns ?

Comment: It doesn't matter. They are the same internally.